# Create a record to HTTP API CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-route53, aws-cdk-typescript

I have a Route53 construct defined as follows which works for my front-end website. The certificate and Route53 are working fine:

```
const myZone = PublicHostedZone.fromPublicHostedZoneAttributes(
    this,
    'ImportedMyHostedZone',
    {
        zoneName: 'example.com',
        hostedZoneId: '######',
    }
);

const certificate = new DnsValidatedCertificate(
    ....
);
```

I want to create a record pointing from my Route53 to my API so that I invoke my API from the following URL: api.example.com, to do this, I tried the following:

```
//This is my API Gateway: 
import * as apigw from '@aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha'
import * as routeTargets from "aws-cdk-lib/aws-route53-targets"


this.myAPI = new apigw.HttpApi(this, 'myAPI', {...//defined other properties})
this.myAPI.addRoutes({
   path: '/submit',
   ##Additional Properties
});

const apiDomainName = 'api.example.com';
const domain = new apigw.DomainName(this, 'MyAPIDomain', {
    domainName: apiDomainName,
    certificate: certificate, //same certificate as defined above (for example.com)
});

const apiMapping = new apigw.ApiMapping(this, 'MyApiMapping', {//Create a mapping for HTTP API
    api: this.myAPI,
    domainName: domain,
    stage: props.httpAPI.defaultStage,
});

new ARecord(this, 'ApiARecord', {
    zone: myZone,
    recordName: apiDomainName,
    target: RecordTarget.fromAlias(new routeTargets.ApiGateway(props.httpAPI)), //Error
});
```

For some reason, I keep getting an error on the line above saying "Argument of type 'HttpApi' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RestApiBase'". I can't find a routeTargers.ApiGatewayv2 so is there any other way to reference my httpAPI as a target in an ARecord definition or is there something I'm doing wrong?

Above all this is my understanding that to create a custom subdomain for my API, I have to 1) Create a mapping from my HTTP API to my subdomain (api.example.com) and I can use the same certificate for my original domain (example.com), 2) Create a new A record in my Route53 that points from my subdomain (api.example.com) to my HTTP API. Are these the only two steps that I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

try to update aws-cdk-lib and @aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha to latest versions

keep in mind that @aws-cdk/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha is in experimental state see link

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-apigatewayv2-alpha-readme.html

Answer (score 0):

This code `new routeTargets.ApiGateway(props.httpAPI)` is used for adding REST API. Not Http API.

For Http API refer this:

```
import * as apigwv2 from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigatewayv2';

declare const zone: route53.HostedZone;
declare const domainName: apigwv2.DomainName;

new route53.ARecord(this, 'AliasRecord', {
  zone,
  target: route53.RecordTarget.fromAlias(new targets.ApiGatewayv2DomainProperties(domainName.regionalDomainName, domainName.regionalHostedZoneId)),
});
```

Source: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_route53_targets-readme.html